# Constant message send for specific channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So im looking to create a channel where a message from my bot gets sent every 10 minutes displaying the current bot stats of that time any ideas?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with a backgroup loop.

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

@tasks.loop(minutes = 10.0)
async def stats():
    pass
```